# NoSuchDriverException: Message: Unable to obtain driver for chrome using Selenium Manager

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver=webdriver.Chrome()
```

it gives the error-

```
NoSuchDriverException: Message: Unable to obtain driver for chrome using Selenium Manager.; For documentation on this error, please visit: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/troubleshooting/errors/driver_location
```

I have visited the website and tried but the problem remain same

I expect that the simple selenium automation code to run

Answer (score 0):

In new versions of selenium you don't need to install drivers manually. In your case the **problem should be with the selenium-manager.exe**

to confirm the problem is with the manager first locate your file location the execute it like this in cmd:

```
C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\windows\selenium-manager.exe --browser chrome --debug --output json
```

If you received an error uninstall and reinstall selenium

```
pip uninstall selenium
pip install selenium
```

Also if you are using `selenium-wire` try the step above for selenium-wire too.

Answer (score -1):

You need to have the Chromedriver or Geckodriver on your machine and in a folder where Selenium can easily access and make use of it to control your Google Chrome or Firefox browser respectively. Have you checked if you have any of these browsers downloaded and unzipped?

Download the Chromedriver here https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads. Please let me know if you need any more help to get your code running.